# dual boot ubuntu12.10 on windows 7

Tags: installation, 12.10, boot

Firstly I booted win 7, then I wanted to boot ubuntu 12.10 on windows. I have ubuntu DVD
and when I try to boot ubuntu and when I press "install ubuntu" proccess starts and laptop becomes like "zombie" DVD stops working and point under ubuntu logo stops moving. 
I have foloving partitions:

- 258 GB: ntfs on (C:)
- 322 GB: ntfs on (D:)
- 117 GB: free space.

I tryed disk defragmentation and disk cleanup, but no sucsess installing ubuntu.
Please help me, what have to I do to install ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way to install ubuntu on your system if you have windows installed in your system. for that you will need a .iso file of your ubuntu. you can make it from your dvd by using softwares like power iso or you can download ubuntu12.10.iso file too.once you have it follow these steps.

1. mount the iso file.
2. find the wubi.exe inside of your iso file
3. copy it to the folder congaing ubuntu.iso file
4. Run Wubi.exe

   > [image: Ubuntu installer on windows]
5. select the drive on which you want to install
6. select installation size
7. Enter the password and click on install
8. it will ask you to restart. now restart.
9. dont press "esc" key after reboot. your installation start automatically.

Comment: And its even easy to uninstall ubuntu from your system too. just go to add-remove programs, click on ubuntu and uninstall it.